# How to get value of selected option of 2 different rows but same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table is in for each loop and its id is set to `id="batchNo"`.

i want to get the value of each row `select option` selected value.

i tried to use following code but it returns row 1 selected value.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="batchNo">
        <option value="341" selected>this is 341</option>
        <option value="53">this is 53</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" onfocusout="return alert($('#batchNo').find(':selected').text())"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="batchNo">
        <option value="341">this is 341</option>
        <option value="53" selected>this is 53</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" onfocusout="return alert($('#batchNo').find(':selected').text())"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

on focusout of 2nd row it shouold return `this is 53` but it gives `this is 341`

Comment: id's in **valid** HTML **must** be unique - so the answer is, you can't do that (reliably) - use `$(this).find....` instead maybe?

Comment: Attribute 'id' **must** be unique. Use 'class' instead.

Comment: use of class won't help this code @wanjas - the first element retrieved by jquery will still be the first select

Comment: @Jaromanda X of course. it's just the first step

Comment: is there some possibility like this $(thisrow).find(tag"select")(':selected').text() this is for example

Comment: `this` ... not `thisrow` ... `this` means something in javascript, `thisrow` is made up -  nevermind, just realised which element you're putting the event listener on

Comment: I'd can't be same. You can use for loop to set id unique and get value from those ids. For eg: batchNo1 and batchNo2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the "relatively" `select`. Here is what you can do:

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  const selectVal = $(this).parents('tr').find('.batchNo').find(':selected').text();
  console.log(selectVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="batchNo">
        <option value="341" selected>this is 341</option>
        <option value="53">this is 53</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="batchNo">
        <option value="341">this is 341</option>
        <option value="53" selected>this is 53</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And, obviously, to avoid duplicate `id`s, you need change to something else, like `class`. (You can also use `data-*` attribute)

Comment: Mosh Feu can u please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5k6q92sd/ as i want its text not value, value is coming correct individually from your code

Answer (score 0):

**First of all using same id for two diffrent elements is bad practice**

**Method 1 (Using Class name)**

```
<select class = 'batchNo'>
</select>

var result = document.querySelectorAll('.batchNo')
console.log(result) // prints list of all select
```

querySelectorAll() will give you list of values and then you can loop over it and get values of all select elements

**Method 2 (Using Id)**

As you said your table is in for loop, then what you can do is get the iteration no. of for loop and generate dynamic id as below

```
<select id="batchNo{{ for loop iteration no }}">
</select>
```

it'll generate id's like batchNo1, batchNo2, batchNo3....

Answer (score 0):

As you've updated the question, I think this answers the problem you specifically need solved. I agree with the previous answers though, it's best to make `id` unique throughout a page.

I've removed your inline code and added a class `.runOnFocusOut` to the inputs, s

1. Some jquery is triggered via `.focusout`
2. which travels up the DOM tree until the parent table row using `.closest("tr")`
3. before travelling back down the DOM tree finding the element with id `#batchNo`, and a child option that is selected with `option:select`
4. and finally printing the text of the option via `.text()`

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for

---

## Demo

```js
// Add focusout event via new class
$(".runOnFocusOut").focusout( function() {

  // Travel up DOM tree
  // Find selected options using option:select
  // Print the text
  console.log(  $(this).closest("tr").find("#batchNo option:selected").text() );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="batchNo">
        <option value="341" selected>this is 341</option>
        <option value="53">this is 53</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="runOnFocusOut"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="batchNo">
        <option value="344">this is 344</option>
        <option value="56" selected>this is 56</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="runOnFocusOut"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```